# Как задействовать RadioButton в диалоговом окне

Tags: java, android

При выборе одного из вариантов `RadioButton` и нажатии кнопки "Выбрать" выводится ошибка:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference
```

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
    View view1 = dialog.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet, null, false);
    Button setStatus = view1.findViewById(R.id.setStatus);
    Button delete = view1.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
                    .setTitle("Удалить")
                    .setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            database.getReference("Text").child(problem.getuId())
                                    .setValue(null);

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).show();

        }
    });

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Text");
    setStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder materialAlertDialogBuilder  = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context);
                    materialAlertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Установить статус");
                    materialAlertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.activity_set_status_problem);
                    materialAlertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                           dialogInterface.dismiss();
                       }
                   });
                    materialAlertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Выбрать", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        RadioGroup radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                        int chekId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        switch (chekId){
                            case R.id.in_work:
                                problem.setStatus("aaa");
                                break;
                            case R.id.put_out:
                                problem.setStatus("bbb");
                        }
                        }
                    });
                    materialAlertDialogBuilder.show();
        }
    });

     dialog.setContentView(view1);
     dialog.show();
     return true;
}
});
```

Comment: приложили бы разметку того по чем нажатия обработать пытаетесь, у вас что setStatus содержит радиокнопку?

Comment: @Andrew Нет, setStatus содержит MaterialAlertDialogBuilder, а materialAlertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton содержит радиокнопку. Точнее радиогруппу, мне надо чтобы при выборе той или иной Радиокнопки сохранялось его значение в конструкторе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
RadioGroup radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
```

Вы ищете радио-группу через ссылку `view`, которая указывает на кнопку, по которой кликнули (`setStatus`) - то есть внутри этой кнопки.

Нужно либо "надуть" разметку `activity_set_status_problem` (создать из неё `View`) и искать там, как у вас сделано для первого `BottomSheetDialog`.
Либо искать радио-группу через ссылку на диалог, в котором она отображается:

```java
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    RadioGroup radioGroup = ((Dialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    int chekId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    ...
```